# How much gold and how much time does fitted mithril or adamantine armor cost?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, crafting, pricing

I'm looking for the most widely accepted rules for buying mithril and adamantine armor, including chain, splint, half and full plate. How much gold and how much time, baseline, does it cost a merchant to craft each piece of armor listed (8 total)?

Non-official rules are allowed as long as they are widely used. I've scoured many sources like the DMG, in addition to the other official 5e sources, and popular homebrews like the [Sane Magic Item Prices](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?424243-Sane-Magic-Item-Prices) guide.

Comment: Related and maybe a duplicate: [What would be the price of Adamantine Plate armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159489/14878)

Comment: I saw this. It did not answer my question.

Comment: It might help to add into your post *why* that doesn’t answer your question then and what more you’re looking for.

Comment: My question is pretty straightforward. I don't think I need to add anymore context. But, in the comments here, I will say that that question, while related, does not cover the materials I mentioned... except adamantine... Nor does it address the time aspect. Also, Sane Magic Prices doesn't mention Mithril plate. Appreciate your diligence... But why don't we give my question a chance, hmm?

Comment: The more information you add to the question (within reason) the better equipped we are to provide you with useful answers. If you’ve already found a *similar* question that *doesn’t* answer your question it can be helpful to have that information in the post so that we’re not going over material you’ve already found and deemed “useless”. If you don’t want to add that info to your question then that’s your prerogative.

Comment: Related: [Do magic items really cost at least as much to create as they do to purchase?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60478)

Comment: Not super-important, but are you asking as a DM or as a player?

Comment: I'm the game's DM. Was asking this because one of the players wanted to buy some Mithril Plate, and I just couldn't figure out the best way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Value

Both [*mithral armor*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/mithral-armor) and [*adamantine armor*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/adamantine-armor) are listed as uncommon magic items. In the guidance on [crafting a magic item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/between-adventures#CraftingaMagicItem) in the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* (p. 128-129), uncommon magic items have a range of value of 101-500 gp.

Obviously, *mithral plate* is not worth less than mundane plate armor, so at my tables we have always just added 500 gp to whatever the value of the mundane version of the armor is to get the value of the mithral or adamantine versions. This has always been well-received by players I’ve played with, and is consistent with the accepted answer to the related question [What would be the price of Adamantine Plate armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159489/what-would-be-the-price-of-adamantine-plate-armor)

#### Time

Time is going to be largely up to the DM. There is some guidance in *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* concerning [crafting magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#CraftinganItem) (p. 128-129); the suggested crafting time for uncommon magic items is two weeks (and 200 gp of other expenses).

#### Bringing it together

If I’m running the game, I’ll let you buy *mithral plate armor* or *adamantine plate armor* for 2000 gp. But if you want to craft it yourself, or that is the avenue your DM has determined for you to take, I would suggest following the guidance on [crafting an item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#CraftinganItem) in *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* (p. 129):

> An item invariably requires an exotic material to complete it. This material can range from the skin of a yeti to a vial of water taken from a whirlpool on the Elemental Plane of Water. **Finding that material should take place as part of an adventure.**

I will work the mithral or adamantine raw materials into the adventure or allow the player to purchase 500 gp worth of it, then allow the player to craft the mithral or adamantine variant of an existing armor during two weeks of downtime.